# How to restructure output of a keras layer?

Tags: python, keras

I want to reconstruct the output shape of my Input layer, in a way that for example if it is (None, 42), I start from 1st neuron and take 1st to 7th, then slide a neuron to right and take 2nd to 8th and so on. in this way output layer would be the shape (None, 36, 7).

I am using keras.layers.Lambda() layer to do that but it is not working properly and dimensions are not what i expect. the code i wrote is as follow:

```
Inpt_lyr = keras.Input(shape = (42,))
for k in range(42 - 7 + 1):
    F = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x, i, j: x[:,j : j + i])
    F.arguments ={ 'i' : 7, 'j' : k}
    tmp_rfrm = F(Inpt_lyr)
    lst_rfrm.append(tmp_rfrm)
cnctnt_lyr = keras.layers.merge.Concatenate(axis = 0)(lst_rfrm)
tmp_dns = keras.layers.Dense(3 , activation = 'softmax')(cnctnt_lyr)
tmp_model = Model(Inpt_lyr, tmp_dns)
tmp_model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam')
tmp_model.summary()
```

I expect conct_lyr have the shape (None, 36, 7), but it is (None,7)
and it also give the error
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_3:0", shape=(?, 42), dtype=float32) at layer "input_3". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: ['input_4']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach looks sensible to me, but the tensors are currently being concatenated along the batch axis, which is undesirable in this case.

I would suggest expanding dimension 1 while sliding the windows:

```
for k in range(42 - 7 + 1):
    F = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x, i, j: x[:, None, j: j + i])
    # F(Inpt_lyr).shape=(?, 1, 7)
```

and then concatenate the tensors along the expanded axis:

```
cnctnt_lyr = keras.layers.merge.Concatenate(axis=1)(lst_rfrm)
# cnctnt_lyr.shape=(?, 36, 7)
```